# Sprite Kit: Label 'jumps' when text changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I Have a label that displays the time that has elapsed in my game since the player first touched the screen. It displays seconds and milliseconds. I have it positioned in the middle of the frame using

```
 CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)
```

The problem is, not all numbers appear to have the same width (for example, 1 is smaller than 3). This causes my label to jump one or two pixels from left to right rapidly when the milliseconds update. Because the label size apparantely increases and decreases every time, the MidX coordinate of my label changes and causes my label to move. I want it to stay at the same position all the time.

Does anyone knows a solution to stop it from moving?

EDIT: label code

```
-(SKLabelNode *) timeLabel
{
timeLabel = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
timeLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame);
timeLabel.fontColor = [SKColor blackColor];
timeLabel.fontSize = fontSize;

timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i,%02i", min, sec, mil];

return tijdLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the alignment of the label to centre like this:

```
timeLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeCenter;
timeLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeCenter;
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean just adding myLabel.text = @"Something long" ? Because this does not seem to do anything, since the label text changes to the timer when the scene starts

Comment: Set the size of you label on the frame property, i.e. myLabel.frame. If still not clear, can you add the code where you initialise your label?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried your suggestion, but it still won't change anything.. The weird thing is when I place a dot or 0 in my label as the last character, the jumping is over. But aligning the text to the left or center doesn't help me out

Comment: After playing around a bit more with the aliignmentMode of my label, I got it right! Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't think this is actually "correct" - it should be, if using monospaced fonts and all but for some reason I am seeing very jumpy labels even using all of the above. It does feel like some kind of unfortunate problem inside of SpriteKit :-P

Answer (score 0):

You have to align the label text to the left. Anything else will make it jitter. Look at the test code below.

```
#import "MyScene.h"

@implementation MyScene
{
    SKLabelNode *timeLabel;
}

-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size
{
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size])
    {        
        timeLabel = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"Arial"];
        timeLabel.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMinY(self.frame));
        timeLabel.fontColor = [SKColor whiteColor];
        timeLabel.fontSize = 20;
        timeLabel.horizontalAlignmentMode = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentModeLeft;
        timeLabel.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentModeBottom;
        [self addChild:timeLabel];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    //
}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",currentTime];
}

@end
```